# How to create an HTML dynamic table with fields that can be modified? (Fields are currently somehow linked to one another)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-table

I have come upon a strange problem while creating a dynamic table in HTML.

I want the user to be able to create new entries into the table, I call them persons in this case.

Each person is an interface of type `PersonInfo`.

```
interface PersonInfo {
    showOtherData: boolean;
    person: Person;
}

interface Person {
   name: string;
   age: number;
}
```

I’ve got an array of persons. Each time a new person is added, it means there is a new row in the HTML table.

I create my table:

```
<table>

<tbody>
```

And then I want to loop through the different persons to show the different data cells:

```
<td>
    <input [(ngModel)]="person.person.name" class="center form-control" type="text"
      placeholder="Name" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Person's name" />
 </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *ngFor if you want to loop the data in the template: I will just assume your list is called 'persons':

```
<td *ngFor="let info of persons">
  <input [(ngModel)]="info?.person?.name" class="center form-control" type="text"
      placeholder="Name" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Person's name" />
</td>
```

This will create a new td for every person in the list.